# Exception in MongoDB while trying to instantiate an abstract class

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, bson

We are using Spring Data for Mongo DB 1.3.3 and are getting an exception on retrieving documents where one of the nested object is of type abstract. *If we change the User class to be concrete then no exception is thrown and code works fine.*

**BSON structure:**

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "52d99dec88c6bd5da9c05a86"},
     "_class": "com.xyz.Quote" , 
     "name" : "sssds" ,
     "quoteNumber" : 1006 ,
      "account" : { "accountNumber" : "060926" ,
                     "phone" : [ ] , "fax" : [ ] ,
                 "leadDealerAccount" : "066418" , 
................................................
"quoteCreatedBy" : { "_class" : "com.xyz.DealerUser" , 
                     "lastName" : "TILLMAN" ,
                    "firstName" : "TIMOTHY" ,
                   "middleName" : "M" 
}
}
```

**POJO classes:**

```
public abstract class User {
   private String lastName;
   private String firstName; 
} 

public class DealerUser extends User {
   private Account primaryAccount;
}

public class AnotherUser extends User{
   private List<Address> availableAddresses;
}

public class Quote {
    private User quoteCreatedBy;
}
```

**Code:**

```
Query searchQuoteQuery = new Query(Criteria.where("account.leadDealerAccount"). is(066418));
List<Quote> mongoTemplate.find(searchQuoteQuery , Quote.class);
```

**Exception**
The last line throws the following exception:

```
[2/7/14 12:54:14:019 CST] 00000032 SystemErr R org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingInst antiationException: Failed to instantiate com.deere.mp.common.domain.User using constructor public com.deere.mp.common.domain.User() with arguments
[2/7/14 12:54:14:020 CST] 00000032 SystemErr R at org.springframework.data.convert.ReflectionEntityI nstantiator.createInstance(ReflectionEntityInstantiator.java:78)
[2/7/14 12:54:14:020 CST] 00000032 SystemErr R at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.Mapp ingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:243)
[2/7/14 12:54:14:020 CST] 00000032 SystemErr R at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.Mapp ingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:223)
[2/7/14 12:54:14:020 CST] 00000032 SystemErr R at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.Mapp ingMongoConverter.readValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1050)
[2/7/14 12:54:14:020 CST] 00000032 SystemErr R at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.Mapp ingMongoConverter.access$100(MappingMongoConverter.java:77)
[2/7/14 12:54:14:020 CST] 00000032 SystemErr R at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.Mapp ingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.get PropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:999)
[2/7/14 12:54:14:020 CST] 00000032 SystemErr R at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.Mapp ingMongoConverter.getValueInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:755)
[2/7/14 12:54:14:020 CST] 00000032 SystemErr R at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.Mapp ingMongoConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:256)
[2/7/14 12:54:14:020 CST] 00000032 SystemErr R at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.Mapp ingMongoConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:249)
[2/7/14 12:54:14:020 CST] 00000032 SystemErr R at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersis tentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:257)
[2/7/14 12:54:14:020 CST] 00000032 SystemErr R at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.Mapp ingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:249)
[2/7/14 12:54:14:021 CST] 00000032 SystemErr R at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.Mapp ingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:223)
[2/7/14 12:54:14:021 CST] 00000032 SystemErr R at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.Mapp ingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:187)
[2/7/14 12:54:14:021 CST] 00000032 SystemErr R at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.Mapp ingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:183)
[2/7/14 12:54:14:021 CST] 00000032 SystemErr R at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.Mapp ingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:77)
[2/7/14 12:54:14:021 CST] 00000032 SystemErr R at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplat e$ReadDbObjectCallback.doWith(MongoTemplate.java:1975)
[2/7/14 12:54:14:021 CST] 00000032 SystemErr R at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplat e.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1671)
[2/7/14 12:54:14:021 CST] 00000032 SystemErr R at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplat e.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1496)
[2/7/14 12:54:14:021 CST] 00000032 SystemErr R at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplat e.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1480)
[2/7/14 12:54:14:021 CST] 00000032 SystemErr R at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplat e.find(MongoTemplate.java:527)
[2/7/14 12:54:14:021 CST] 00000032 SystemErr R at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplat e.find(MongoTemplate.java:518)
[2/7/14 12:54:14:021 CST] 00000032 SystemErr R at com.deere.mp.quote.dao.impl.QuoteDAOImpl.findByUse rId(QuoteDAOImpl.java:137)
[2/7/14 12:54:14:021 CST] 00000032 SystemErr R at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[2/7/14 12:54:14:021 CST] 00000032 SystemErr R at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
[2/7/14 12:54:14:021 CST] 00000032 SystemErr R at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
```

Answer (score 1):

Annotate your classes with **@BsonDiscriminator**:

```
@org.bson.codecs.pojo.annotations.BsonDiscriminator()
public class DealerUser {}
```

Also if the `User` class is a property/field of an other class you have to annotate that field with **@BsonProperty(useDiscriminator = true)**:

```
public class Some class {

    @org.bson.codecs.pojo.annotations.BsonProperty(useDiscriminator = true)
    private User user;

}
```

Answer (score -4):

It is so very obvious from the stacktrace(as well as Java basic logic) that you cannot instantiate a abstract class in Java. Then how do you expect the Spring Data APIs to populate JSON data into classes which cannot be instantiated?? Spring will fetch data from mongodb and try to push the same data into POJOs of the specified class(which in your case is abstract and cant instantiate).

Comment: Is there any way to achieve the expected behavior?